# Enable MARS in Laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

For my Laravel application, I want to use MARS to connect to our SQL server. However, the documentation makes no note of this, nor is there any info on how to pass extra config parameters to the connection.
I'm on Laravel v7.30.
The database works fine apart for the few cases where I need to run several queries on one connection. Right now, those throw a "Protocol error in TDS stream" error. I'm fairly certain this is due to MARS not being activated. If, however, this could have a different reason I'm of course open to suggestions!

My `config/database.php` entry for SQL Server looks like this:

```
'sqlsrv' => [
      'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
      'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
      'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
      'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
      'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
      'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
      'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
      'charset' => 'utf8',
      'prefix' => '',
      'prefix_indexes' => true,
      'appname' => env('DB_APPNAME', 'MyAppName-' . env('APP_ENV')),
],
```

Apart from that, the database connection is working fine and queries perform as expected.

Comment: I could be very wrong but I think it's already enabled. I've had a quick glance at the `SqlServerConnector` class and there is only an option to disable it https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v7.30.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/SqlServerConnector.php#L131. I don't use sqlsrv so I'm not really able to offer anything else, however, this might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/103846/protocol-error-in-tds-stream-ssis-when-running-wit.html

Comment: @Rwd oof, not much I can dispute about that. I suppose my route of thinking must be wrong then. Thanks for digging up the source, I should've taken the time to do that.

Comment: No worries at all. I hope you manage to get to the bottom of it :)